# \text vs \scalebox

Tags: graphics, amsmath

The author of a manuscript I'm editing is using the `\medcup` macro in the MWE below. We've noticed the scaling it totally off if used inside the `\text` command. Can anyone explain why?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}%,scalerel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\medcup{%
  \operatornamewithlimits{%
    \mathchoice{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{1.2}{$\bigcup$}}}}
    {\vcenter{\hbox{$\bigcup$}}}%
    {\bigcup}%
    {\bigcup}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\[
  \text{Inside \cs{text}: $ \medcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} $}
\]

\[
  \text{Not inside \cs{text}: }  \medcup_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I have never noticed it: also `\def\foo{\mathchoice{D}{T}{S}{SS}}` and then `\[\foo \text{$\foo$}\]` yields D in both cases.

Comment: @campa I think this is a specifically designed feature, it is nice that `\text{xxx $\int_1^2 f dx$}` does get the same size as outside `\text`. But it does not explain why the size goes of the charts in this case.

Comment: Because `\medcup` just uses `$\bigcup$` it would normally show a scaled version of the text style symbol in a display environment. When `\text` is called in a display environment it calls `\everymath{\displaystyle}` which means that the top equation contains a display style `\bigcup`, scaled by a factor 1.2, and the bottom one is a text style `\bigcup`, also scaled by a factor 1.2.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the fact that `\[\text{$\mathchoice{D}{T}{S}{s}$}\]` produces a `D` and not a `T`.

Comment: @Circumscribe, right, that makes sense and explicitly adding a `\textstyle` into the definition fixes it. Thanks. Do you mind submitting that as an answer.

Comment: By the way, `\operatornamewithlimits` has been deprecated for several years in favor of `\operatorname*`. Using `\def` is, of course, always deprecated. Also, the definition `\vcenter{\hbox{$\bigcup$}` can be just `\bigcup`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When `\medcup` is used in a display equation, it normally produces a scaled version of a text style `\bigcup`. What is happening in your first equation, however, is that a scaled version of the display style `\bigcup` is used instead because `\text` causes a `\displaystyle` command to be inserted in `$\bigcup$`.

The `\text` command is designed so that any equations in its argument are typeset in the current math style, which is `\displaystyle` in this case.
Its definition contains a `\mathcoice`, whose `\displaystyle` branch is effectively given by

```
\hbox{{\everymath{\displaystyle}\let\f@size\f@size\selectfont #1}}
```

Because this sets `\everymath={\displaystyle}`, `\displaystyle` will be inserted at the start of *every* equation inside the argument of `\text`.
This includes the first `$\bigcup$` in the definition of `\medcup`.
Your first equation therefore effectively becomes

```
\[
  \hbox{Inside \cs{text}: 
    $\displaystyle
      \operatornamewithlimits{
        \vcenter{\hbox{{\scalebox{1.2}{$\displaystyle\bigcup$}}}}
      }_{n = 1}^{\infty}
    $
  }
\]
```

and thus produces a scaled version of the display style version of `\bigcup`, rather than the text style version.

---

To ensure that the text style version of `\bigcup` is always used, you can explicitly insert a `\textstyle` in the definition of `\medcup`:

```
\newcommand*\medcup{%
  \operatorname*{%
    \mathchoice{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{1.2}{$\textstyle\bigcup$}}}}%
    {\bigcup}%
    {\bigcup}%
    {\bigcup}%
  }%
}
```

*(I also replaced the deprecated `\operatnamewithlimits` by `\operatorname*` and simplified the `\textstyle` branch, as suggested by egreg in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446413/text-vs-scalebox/446424#comment1121348_446413).)*

Answer (score 8):

It has  to do with the fact that `\[\text{$\mathchoice{D}{T}{S}{s}$}\]` produces `D`isplaystyle and not  `T`extstyle.

Thus, adding `\textstyle` in the definition is needed to overcome this behavior.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}%,scalerel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\medcup{%
  \operatornamewithlimits{%
    \mathchoice{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{1.2}{$\bigcup$}}}}
    {\vcenter{\hbox{$\bigcup$}}}%
    {\bigcup}%
    {\bigcup}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\[
  \text{Inside \cs{text}: $\textstyle \medcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} $}
\]

\[
  \text{Not inside \cs{text}: }  \medcup_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\]

\[\text{$\mathchoice{D}{T}{S}{s}$}\]
\[\bigcup\scalebox{1.2}{$\bigcup$}\text{$\scalebox{1.2}{$\bigcup$}$}\]
\[\bigcup\scalebox{1.2}{$\bigcup$}\text{$\scalebox{1.2}{$\textstyle\bigcup$}$}\]

\def\medcup{%
  \operatornamewithlimits{%
    \mathchoice{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{1.2}{$\textstyle\bigcup$}}}}
    {\vcenter{\hbox{$\textstyle\bigcup$}}}%
    {\bigcup}%
    {\bigcup}%
  }%
}

\[
  \text{Inside \cs{text}: $\textstyle \medcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} $}
\]

\[
  \text{Not inside \cs{text}: }  \medcup_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The first two lines of output are from the OP's original definition.  Then I demonstrate the display/text-style issue with the "D" line.

Then I show on the next line how the 3rd bigcup should be the same as the 2nd but isn't because of this behavior.

The next line fixes that by explicitly invoking `\textstyle`.

Finally, I change the OP's definition, explicitly adding `\textstyle`, to fix the overall issue.